# How can I access a public static int variable in another class/file?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static, include

The IDE I am using is Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 and I am following a guide for game development.

I have the following code:

```
//Game.h
#pramga once
class Game{
public:
    Game();
    static int mapWidth;
};

//Game.cpp
#include "Game.h"

//Initialization
int Game::mapWidth;

//Implementation class
Game::Game(){
mapWidth = 10;
};

//Camera.h
#pragma once
#include "Game.h"

class Camera{
    Camera() = default;
    void update(){
      if (Game::mapWidth > 0)
          //do something
    }
};
```

What is interesting is that if I hover over this variable in Camera.h the IDE recognizes the variable and where its coming from. But, when i go to compile i get the following error from my if statement:

```
C2653 'Game': is not a class or namespace name
```

I am using the scope resolution operator and my vairable is public static and initialized in Game.cpp/h. So, why am I getting this compile error when the IDE recognizes the variable and the Game class as existing?

Comment: Missing semicolon after the class definition: `class Game { /*...*/ };` The same for `Camera`.

Comment: Are you using include guards and are they distinct?  Do you have recursive includes ie does  `Camera.h` include `Game.h` which includes `Camera.h` either directly or indirectly ?

Comment: Did you test the code with the semicolons that quickly? Make sure your shown code is _exactly_ what you tested.

Comment: @user17732522 While that may have been relevant to what I typed, it should be assumed that is not the case in my actual code.

Comment: @MichaelElrod The problem is that the missing semicolon could result in issues similar to this.

Comment: @MichaelElrod we ask for a [mcve] and what's in the question is supposed to have been test by you before posting to ensure it duplicates the issue.

Comment: The next problem is that the constructor is not declared inside the class and that the `if` statement is at class scope when only declarations can appear there. `if` must be in a function body (at block scope).

Comment: These above mentions have been edited in my question , but these issues were never present in my actual code.

Comment: The code you are showing now will not produce that error.  However, you are probably missing at least one additional `.cpp` file that includes `Camera.h` since header files themselves should not be compiled as translation units. But even if `Camera.h` is compiled as translation unit there will not be any error (except for one about a missing statement/block after the `if` head).

Comment: @RichardCritten Recursive includes. Also mentioned in a below comment this was the source of my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing a trailing semicolon at the end of your `Game` class definition. Definitions of structs and classes in C++, unlike in other languages, end in closing bracket AND a semicolon. Such an error might be hard to spot (depending on your IDE). When the preprocessor includes `Game.h` in `Game.cpp`, it puts it right above the initialization of `Game::mapWidth`, which causes it to get invalidated.

Proper definition should like this:

```
class Game {
public:
    static int mapWidth;
    Game(); // <-- declaration of constructor should be here 
}; // <-- note the semicolon
```

This is the case for your `Camera` class as well.

```
class Camera{
    if (Game::mapWidth > 0)
         //do something
}; // Semicolon
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I made these changes in my question, but unfortunately these issues werent in my actual code so that's on me for not typing them here properly.

Comment: Would you be able to post what your exact code looks like if its not too long? This type of issue also happens when you have a circular dependency or an include guard missing, are you sure that that is not the case?

Comment: Unfortunatley this program is a game engine and is a collection of over 10 separate files. I will take this into consideration and review my dependencies, but I'm failry confident I dont have #include recursion. For protection gaurds I am using #pragma once.

Comment: After extensive review I have found the issue and you were correct. I had a case of circular dependency with my header file inculdes in my program. Thank you.